# How to re-structure this code to be more efficient? 8086 Lift Simulator

Tags: assembly, x86-16

How would I change this code around to be more efficient or even different in any way? Would it be a good idea to use procedures rather than loops, anything to cut down on the RAM usage, as I'm really struggling. The lift simulator basically needs to go up and down again without crashing.

```
; ------------------------ THE LIFT ----------------------------
Start:
CLO
OR  AL, 00 
OUT 06      ; Display lift window

; --------------------------------------------------------------
; A LOOP THAT CONTROLS THE LIFT WHEN IDLE
Idle:
IN  06      ; Read lift status
AND AL, 20      ; Isolate UP button bit
JNZ Up      ; If UP button pressed, jump to UP
IN  06      ; Read lift status
AND AL, 10      ; Isolate DOWN button bit
JNZ Down        ; If DOWN button pressed, jump to DOWN
JMP Idle        ; Jump back to Idle

; --------------------------------------------------------------
; A LOOP TO CONTROL THE LIFT WHEN GOING UP
Up:
MOV AL, 21      ; Move hex value 21 to AL
OUT 06      ; Display lift status
MOV [AF], AL    ; Move contents of AL to RAM location AF
IN  06      ; Read lift status
AND AL, 4       ; Clear Bit 4 for use
JNZ Stop        ; Stop if lift is close enough
MOV AL, [AF]    ; Move contents of RAM location AF to AL
JMP Idle        ; Jump back to Idle

; --------------------------------------------------------------
; A LOOP TO CONTROL THE LIFT WHEN GOING DOWN
Down:
MOV AL, 12      ; Move hex value 12 to AL
OUT 06      ; Display the lift status
MOV [AF], AL    ; Move contents of AL to RAM location AF
IN  06      ; Read lift status
AND AL, 8       ; Clear Bit 8 for use
JNZ Stop        ; Stop if lift is close enough
MOV AL, [AF]    ; Move contents of RAM location AF to AL
JMP Idle        ; Jump back to Idle

; --------------------------------------------------------------
; A PROCEDURE TO STOP THE LIFT AT THE TOP AND BOTTOM
Stop:
MOV AL, AF      ; 
MOV AL, 0       ; 
OUT 06      ;
JMP Idle

; --------------------------------------------------------------
END
; --------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This probably belongs over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: 1) Does it work? (Does it even "not crash"?) How do you know?   2) What optimization do you think it needs, and why?  [Minimize memory usage? You mean "data storage" or "code space"?  Frankly,this is a toy program which argues against any serious optimization.    When you have a long,nasty computation or 10,000 lines of code, "optimization" start to make sense.   But I don't see much need, here, if any.

Comment: Re-Think this,  `AND AL, 4   ; Clear Bit 4 for use`  You are clearing all the **other** bits **except**  bit 2

Answer (score 1):

Here are two things that you could do.

The first `Idle:` section can be reduced from 7 instructions to 5 instructions like this...

```
 Idle:

    IN      06              ; Read lift status
    AND     AL, 30h         ; Check the Up and down buttons
    JZ      Idle            ; Nope, neither button pushed

    TEST    AL, 20h         ; Up button pressed ?
    JNZ     Up              ; Yes, go do it

                            ; ---ELSE--- Down button is pushed, so fall through
 Down:
    :
    :
    :
```

Also, you have an instruction that is destroyed by the one after it, so you can remove it completely...

```
Stop:

    MOV AL, AF              ; This instruction can be removed
    MOV AL, 0               ; 
    OUT 06                  ;
    JMP Idle
```